# How to aggregate python tasks for certain period and execute each task only once

Tags: python, django

Consider a generic app that give its users points each time they do something good

I have the model

```
class GoodDeed(models.Model):
     user = models.ForgeinKey(CustomUser)
     points = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

class CustomUser(models.Model):
     points = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
     rank = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now each time a new deed is added total points of that user is recalculated and each time user's points are recalculated ranking of all users (against other users) is recalculated as well.

This is horrible, I want to aggregate all ranking update requests and execute it only once every few minutes. Is there any python library that can do something like this?

A cron job is an option but it would update the ranking of all users every few minutes regardless of whether the update is needed or not.

EDIT: Based on @The Django Ninja's suggestion I wrote this decorator and sharing it

## USAGE:

```
    class CustomUser(models.Model):

        @cached_model_property
        def points(self):
            del self.rank  # removed cached rank value
            return sum(self.good_deeds.values_list("points", flat=True))

        @cached_model_property(readonly=False)
        def rank(self):
            user_list = []
            for user in User.onjects.all().only("points")
                user_list.push((user.points, user))
            # sort the list
            user_list.sort(reverse=True)
            # update all ranking
            rank = 0
            my_rank = None
            for points, user in user_list:
                rank += 1
                if user.pk == self.pk:
                    # Don't update this instance's rank yet, as it will be
                    # updated when the function return
                    my_rank = rank
                    continue
                # Save the new rank in the cache
                user.rank = rank
            # If you forget to return something (not None) caching will always assumed to be invalid
            return my_rank
```

## Effect

```
>>> user.points
# call points() method, cache the result, return it
>>> user.points
# return cached result without calling points() method
>>> del user.points
>>> user.points
# call points() method, cache the result, return it

>>> user.rank
# 1. Calculate and save (in cache) rank of all users except current user
# 2. Cache current user's rank and return it
>>> user.rank
# return cached user's rank
>>> del user.points
>>> user.rank
# Recalculate user's points and all ranking values 
>>> user.points = 9
# Readonly property exception
```

Cached rank value for user with id 20 will be stored in a cache key called
'User.20.rank'

## Decorator code

```
def cached_model_property(f=None, **kwargs):
    """
    cached_model_property is a decorator for model functions that takes no arguments
    The function is converted into a property that support caching out of the box
    Sample usage:

    class Team(models.Model):

        @cached_model_property
        def points(self):
            # Do complex DB queries
            return result

        @cached_model_property(readonly=False)
        def editable_points(self):
            # get result
            return result

    Now try
    team = Team.objects.first()
    team.points  <-- complex DB queries will happen, result will be returned
    team.points  <-- this time result is returned from cache (points function is not called at all!
    del team.points <-- points value has been removed from cache
    team.points  <-- complex DB queries will happen, result will be returned

    set readlonly parameter False to make the property writeable
    team.editable_points = 88
    in this case the assigned value will replace the value stored in the cache
    team.editable_points
    returns 88
    """

    readonly = kwargs.get("readonly", True)

    def func(f):
        def _get_cache_key(obj):
            model_name = obj.__class__.__name__
            method_name = f.__name__
            return "%s.%s.%s" % (model_name, obj.pk, method_name)

        def getX(obj):
            """
            This decorator can convert any function that **doesn't** take any arguments into a cached property
            :param obj: model object instance (python provide it by default to class members)
            :return: the cached value if present otherwise call the actual method

            Note:
            This decorator doesn't work if the model function return None.
            The function will be called as long as it return None, no caching!
            """
            # Try to get the cache key for that method
            cache_key = _get_cache_key(obj)
            result = cache.get(cache_key)
            # If not cached, call the actual method and cache the result
            if result is None:
                result = f(obj)
                cache.set(cache_key, result)
            return result

        def delX(obj):
            """
            Remove that property from the cache
            :param obj:
            :return: None
            """
            cache_key = _get_cache_key(obj)
            # Remove that key from the cache
            cache.delete(cache_key)

        def setX(obj, value):
            """
            Set the cache value of that property
            :param obj:
            :return: None
            """
            cache_key = _get_cache_key(obj)
            # Remove that key from the cache
            cache.set(cache_key, value)

        if readonly:
            return property(fget=getX, fdel=delX)
        else:
            return property(fget=getX, fset=setX, fdel=delX)

    # f (= class method) is passed when using @cached_model_property
    if f:
        return func(f)
    # f is not passed when using @cached_model_property(readonly=True) or even @cached_model_property()
    return f
```

Comment: *"Now each time a new deed is added total points of that user is recalculated and each time user's points are recalculated ranking of all users (against other users) is recalculated as well."* - well, **why?!** Why aren't they *properties* of the `CustomUser`, calculated *as needed*, rather than whenever a `GoodDeed` is added? I wouldn't make either `points` or `rank` an attribute.

Comment: Celery is a good python library for asynchronous tasks http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe, to calculate user's rank you need to calculate each user's total points (=sum of his gooddeed points). can you imagine executing these queries each time a user open his home page?

Comment: @MarkGalloway Celery is great but if 10 users got new points in one minute the rank recalculation task will be executed 10 times. I am trying to avoid this

Comment: @Ramast yes, I can; I don't think it would take all that long!

Comment: @Ramast not to mention that it's enough easier to implement that you could do so and find out if there's a problem at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe we already have this implementation you suggest and its making the django code that deal with points / ranking very complicated. Performance deteriorate the more users we get. Also this is just an example to explain what I want but the real project does more DB calculations and finding way to reduce it is totally worth it for us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mentionned above, the ranking task seems to do some heavy duty stuff on the database.

I would go for a basic cache invalidation solution, if a user rank is updated the cache should be invalidated :

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def the_function_that_update_user_rank()
    # updating the rank of the user
    # when the rank is updated we set our cache key (global-rank-update-needed) to True
    cache.set('global-rank-update-needed', 'True')
```

Then a manage.py command should be called every x seconds by a cron job, the command will check from the cache if 'global-rank-update-needed' is True and then update the global rank :

```
from django.core.cache import cache

class UpdateGlobalRank(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'


    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if cache.get('global-rank-update-needed') == 'True':
            # here do the update rank stuff
            print 'Updating the Global Rank'
        cache.set('global-rank-update-needed', 'False')
```

Following This approach the global rank will only be updated if some user's rank changed

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ninja, that does help my problem indeed

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [`celery`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) for these type of tasks.

t’s a task queue with focus on real-time processing, while also supporting task scheduling

Comment: Celery is great but doesn't solve my problem.
My problem is that if 10 users got new points in one minute the rank recalculation task will be executed 10 times. I am trying to avoid this. Celery doesn't help AFAIK it will only run the 10 tasks in the background